# Azure DevOps - standard practice for handling status for multiple stakeholders

Tags: azure-devops, kanban

I'm curious with usage of DevOps boards/sprints/kanban, what is the industry standard for handling usage by multiple stakeholders?

More specifically, DevOps comes with standard states like "Active/Resolved/etc", but what if we want to capture more, such as "Deployed to env X", or even testing statuses.  I know we *can* add additional statuses, but is that the right thing to do?

The challenge we have, is if the Kanban is used, then all those statuses must be represented on the Kanban, because movement on that board actually *sets* the status, so if we remove a status column from the Kanban, any WI with that status would effectively be hidden.

So effectively, I've added a bunch of statuses to cater for environments, testing, different reasons for on-hold, etc, but its being argued that this makes the Kanban too complex to get an easy snapshot of whats happening.

It's been suggested that we remove all these statuses, and instead use Tags and Swimlanes, which seems much less robust to me, it accomplishes the same thing, but without a single source of truth like the status provides.

Just curious if anyone with more experience with DevOps can shed light on how they've tackled this.

Comment: To me, if a work item can be in different logical states based on the stakeholder viewing it, that would call for tagging, as you can apply as many tags as you like. You then build reports and dashboards by evaluating those tags. The alternative would be to alter the process to add specific status fields that correspond to your stakeholder needs, like "Requirements Status", "Dev Status", "Test Status", "Acceptance Status", etc., and put smaller lists of values in those fields. That seems like an overly large solution, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you want to get feature which is not implemented - [Allow multiple states in the KanBan Board Columns](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/allow-multiple-states-in-the-kanban-board-columns/627169)

> Actually the TFS allows only one state for every column in the KanBan Board which makes the whole developing process messy. We had to create several columns for all the states that our dev team has. It would be great if TFS could allow to assign multiple states to the columns, and doing and done columns to reduce the number of columns in the whole process.

There is no way to overcome this and what you need.

You can create custom field with pick list and then configure Kanban to display this field on the board:

[image]

This maybe helps you a bit.